# Send UILocalNotification to main Notifications area instead of Alert

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I'm developing an iOS App which makes a local notification as an Alert on screen inside the app. I want it to send the notification to the main Notifications area and not alert anything on screen instead. How can I do this?

At the moment the notification area just says "No Notifications".

Here's my code:

AppDelegate

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder"
                                                        message:notification.alertBody
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
        // Set icon badge number to zero
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

ViewController

```
self.itemText.text = @"Notification";
NSDate *pickerDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5];
NSLog(@"Picked date is %@", pickerDate);

NSDate *todaysDate;
todaysDate = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"Todays date is %@", todaysDate);


// Schedule the notification
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = pickerDate;
// TO DO : Assign proper text to self.itemText.text based on real data
localNotification.alertBody = self.itemText.text;
localNotification.alertAction = @"Another";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Comment: So, you are basically pushing a `UILocalNotification`. When you receive the notification inside the app, you are supposed to present an alert inside the app. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

UILocalNotification will be added to the main Notifications area only if application is in background or terminated. In the foreground it will call your method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

The only way you can get what you want, is to use `UserNotifications.framework` (since **iOS 10**).

[Introduction to User Notifications Framework in iOS 10](http://www.appcoda.com/ios10-user-notifications-guide/) is just the first tutorial

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH5-SW1) is the Apple Documentation on Local Notifications

And using it, don't forget to implement method of `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` to get Native notification even if your application is in foreground.

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center 
   willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification 
     withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering my question. At the moment there's nothing in the main Notifications area even when application is in background, although I can see a badge on the app. What am I missing? We're working on iOS 9.2 unfortunately :(

Comment: text should be added at 
localNotification.alertBody (currently it's empty) and soundName should be set to UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName or whatever.

Comment: yup got that in the ViewController. it's getting the alert on the app screen but not in the Notifications area when app is in background

Comment: and even supporting of old versions you can implement new iOS features, like I did in my app by using iOS versions check. I'm sure your customer will be delighted.

Comment: so remove - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification method or its implementation if you don't need the alert